# My Interstitial failed to load after i updated the app version. Its still showing for the previous version

Tags: android-studio

After i updated my app version code, the interstitial failed to load. I tried all the means to get them back but my attempts failed. Anyone who could be having a solution.
here is my gradle code

I haven't made any change on the Main Activity and xml activity

gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.christmasloans.christmasloans_quickfestiveloans"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 5
        versionName "5.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner
        "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
            'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-
    core:3.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.0.1'
}
```

kindly check on the code and tell me where i could have messed with my code